# Is there an elegant way to return subpage using generic method?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Let’s assume we have base_page class and some other pages that inherit from base page like project page. Base page has method which accepts tuple with way how to find element (By.XPATH for example) and name of selector, finds element and clicks it. I want to return object of type of subpage that was clicked but not sure if it’s even possible. If I do return self It will return me object of next page but how to make it return me obcject of specific type for eg. project type? Is there any built in magic method? Or maybe I could use dictionary and sanitize parameter to reflect specific webpage (it will probably grow bigger and bigger). Question is maybe chaotic because I’m not sure how to name it. Some kind of generator? Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Post your code and the error you are getting so we can better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: There is no error or actual code yet. Rather I’m thinking about general approach to this problem. I don’t want to have methods like: got_to_projects, go_to_somewhere_else which will return corresponding page types. Rather would like to have one method go_to with parameter and then return specific type of page basing on it.